# Very Disappointed with JS from successful websites

Tags: javascript

I've been learning web development for about a year. Then I started applying what I learnt in a website (which I haven't completed yet). Unfortunately when I saved the JS and Html files of some successful websites like Amazon,facebook, and some others, I was shocked with an entirely different approach in writing JS in particular. it was very hard to read and understand.Questions:

1. Why they use OOP in most of their JS. what I learnt is that OOP is only       required in some cases, however most professional websites use oop nearly everywhere in their JS files??
2. Why they never give meaningfull names to the objects and functions?
3. It seems that they are writing JS in its hardest way. am I right? but why?
4. Does it mean that in order to make a successful website, JS must be written in that same way of complexity???

I have actually learnt everything about JS, and very aware of the performance issues which would emerge  as a result of bad usage of DOM. But these JS files have really turned me off. here are some shots:

```
Array)for(var c=0;c<a[b].length;c++)a[b][c]();a[b]=!0},add:function(b,c){for(var e=1,f=function(){--e<=0&&g(c)},h=b.length;h--;)a[b[h]]!==!0&&((a[b[h]]=a[b[h]]||[]).push(f),e++);f()}}},m=function(a){a=a||{};this.context=a.context||d;this.once=a.once||!1;this.async=a.async||!1;this.observers=[];this.notifyCount=0;this.notifyArgs=[]};m.prototype={notify:function(){this.notifyCount++;if(!(this.once&&this.notifyCount>1)){this.notifyArgs=[].slice.call(arguments);for(var a=0;a<this.observers.length;a++)this._run(this.observers[a])}},
observe:function(a){if(e(a))if(this.once&&this.isNotified())this._run(a);else return this.observers.push(a),this.observers.length-1},remove:function(a){return a>-1&&a<this.observers.length?(this.observers[a]=function(){},!0):!1},boundObserve:function(){var a=this;return function(){a.observe.apply(a,arguments)}},isNotified:function(){return this.notifyCount>0},_run:function(a){var b=this.notifyArgs,c=this.context;this.async?g(function(){a.apply(c,b)}):a.apply(c,b)}};var p=function(){var a={},b=0,k=
{},o=n(),p={},i=function(a){this.data={name:"nav:"+b++,group:"rcx-nav",value:null,result:null,immediate:!0,process:!1,override:!1,resolved:!1,watched:!1,context:k,when:[],iff:[],filter:[],observe:[],stats:{defined:c(),resolved:-1,buildStarted:-1,buildCompleted:-1,callCount:0,executionTime:0}};for(var e in a)a.hasOwnProperty(e)&&(this.data[e]=a[e]);if(this.data.name.indexOf("]")>-1&&(a=this.data.name.split("]"),a.length===2&&a[0].length>1&&a[1].length>0))this.data.name=a[1],this.data.group=a[0].replace("[",
"")};i.prototype={getDependencyNames:function(){for(var a=[].concat(this.data.when,this.data.filter)
```

You can download such files from any website. I would reallly love to see any explanation about this real life issue. and many thanks in advance

Comment: These websites uglify and obfoscate their code, thats why

Comment: You obviously haven't learnt everything to do with JS...

Comment: Do you really think a human programmer wrote that garbage? Nobody is *that* masochistic.

Comment: about oop, you can simplify it as 'oop === structure'. If you have a huge pile of code you have to handle, structure really helps. No offense, but the way you talk shows, that you're pretty new to JS and development in general. Sry. to disappoint you, but there is still a long way to go; you've just started learning, but that's ok.

Comment: No offence mate, because indeed I am new to JS; I have learnt all the basics, but not all the tricks and approaches. I am a PhD student in mathematics and not a web developer, but interested in the field ; and some day I will be good, just as good as you are (probably). Thanks a lot to every one who removed the confusion. I am really happy with your quick helpful answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look to https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

And read about javascript compression.

This uglification is done to improve performance, and its done by tools of course we do not write JS like that.

Maybe you need to read a bit more about javascript programming :

- https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/
- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3#.jp098cpni

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This is a minified file, e.g. it has not been authored that way but generated from another source file.

Also, many sites use some frameworks and/or precompilers which generate (at least) part of the code. You can't really judge from the JS you can download how it has been written.

Answer (score 2):

the reason professional sites have javascript files that look like this is because they are [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

This reduces the transport time as the file will be much smaller and means that parsing can begin more quickly.

The files that developers use will look completely different